# Setting Up a Basic Class In PHP

Tags: php

I am coming from a new background in Java and am now trying to expand my horizons. I have a basic understanding of PHP, BUT I am no expert. I have a basic class written as below

```
<?php

/**
 * Controls and modifies the elements of the 
 *
 * @author Tyler
 */
abstract class Element {
    // Global variables
    public $x_position = 0;
    public $y_position = 0;


    // First Constructor
    public function Element () {
        $x_position = 0;
        $y_position = 0;
    }

    // Second Constructor
    public function Element ($x, $y) {
        $x_position = $x;
        $y_position = $y;
    }
}
```

I am using netbeans IDE to develop this concept for a complex element on a website. BUT if I can't understand this, how do I expect to get this done. I am getting syntax error warnings from my IDE, and I am not familiar enough with PHP to know why . . . yet. Any suggestions?

*** UPDATE ***

I have updated my code after doing a little bit more research. would you look over this and see if I did this right

```
<?php

/**
 * Controls and modifies the elements of the 
 *
 * @author Tyler
 */
abstract class Element {
    protected $x_position;
    protected $y_position;

    function _construct() {
    }


    // creates an instance of Elements without setting a position
    public function withoutPosition () {
        $instance = new self();
        $this -> x_position = 0;
        $this -> y_position = 0;
        return $instance;
    }

    // creates an instance of Elements and sets a position
    public function withPosition ($x, $y) {
        $instance = new self();
        $this -> x_position = $x;
        $this -> y_position = $y;
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

***FINAL UPDATE***

```
/**
 * Basic class of web elements in web design app. 
 * 
 * @category element
 * @copyright (c) 2015, Tyler Lazenby
 * @author Tyler Lazenby
 */
abstract class Element {

    /**
     * horizontal position relative to left side of window.
     * @var int 
     */
    private $x_pos;

    /**
     * vertical position relative to top of window.
     * @var int 
     */
    private $y_pos;

    /**
     * vertical length of containing rectangle.
     * @var double 
     */
    private $length;

    /**
     * horizontal width of containing rectangle.
     * @var double 
     */
    private $width;

    /**
     * css hex code value of foreground color.
     * @var string 
     */
    private $fg_color;

    /**
     * css hex code value of background color.
     * @var string
     */
    private $bg_color;

    /**
     * Default contructor.
     */
    function _construct() {

    }

    /**
     * creates an instance of Element with default values.
     * @return \self
     */
    public static function makeDefault() {
        $instance = new self();
        $this->x_pos = 0;
        $this->y_pos = 0;
        $this->length = 1;
        $this->width = 1;
        $this->fg_color = "#FFFFFF";
        $this->bg_color = "#FFFFFF";
        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * creates an instance of Element and sets a position.
     * @param int $new_x
     * @param int $new_y
     * @return \self
     */
    public static function makePosOnly($new_x, $new_y) {
        $instance = new self();
        $this->x_pos = $new_x;
        $this->y_pos = $new_y;
        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * creates an instance of Element and sets a size.
     * @param double $new_length
     * @param double $new_width
     * @return \self
     */
    public static function makeSizeOnly($new_length, $new_width) {
        $instance = new self();
        $this->length = $new_length;
        $this->width = $new_width;
        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * creates an instance of Element and sets a Fg color and Bg color.
     * @param string $newFgColor
     * @param string $newBgColor
     * @return \self
     */
    public static function makeColorOnly($newFgColor, $newBgColor) {
        $instance = new self();
        $this->fg_color = $newFgColor;
        $this->bg_color = $newBgColor;
        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * creates an instance of Element and sets a position and size.
     * @param int $new_x
     * @param int $new_y
     * @param double $new_length
     * @param double $new_width
     * @return \self
     */
    public static function makePosSize($new_x, $new_y, $new_length, $new_width) {
        $instance = new self();
        $this->x_pos = $new_x;
        $this->y_pos = $new_y;
        $this->length = $new_length;
        $this->width = $new_width;
        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * creates an instance of Element and sets a postion, Fg color, and Bg color.
     * @param int $new_x
     * @param int $new_y
     * @param string $newFgColor
     * @param string $newBgColor
     * @return \self
     */
    public static function makePosColor($new_x, $new_y, $newFgColor, $newBgColor) {
        $instance = new self();
        $this->x_pos = $new_x;
        $this->y_pos = $new_y;
        $this->fg_color = $newFgColor;
        $this->bg_color = $newBgColor;
        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * creates an instance of Element and sets a size, Fg color, and Bg color.
     * @param double $new_length
     * @param double $new_width
     * @param string $newFgColor
     * @param string $newBgColor
     * @return \self
     */
    public static function makeSizeColor($new_length, $new_width, $newFgColor, $newBgColor) {
        $instance = new self();
        $this->length = $new_length;
        $this->width = $new_width;
        $this->fg_color = $newFgColor;
        $this->bg_color = $newBgColor;
        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * creates an instance of Element and sets all attributes.
     * @param int $new_x
     * @param int $new_y
     * @param double $new_length
     * @param double $new_width
     * @param string $newFgColor
     * @param string $newBgColor
     * @return \self
     */
    public static function makeAll($new_x, $new_y, $new_length, $new_width, $newFgColor, $newBgColor) {
        $instance = new self();
        $this->x_pos = $new_x;
        $this->y_pos = $new_y;
        $this->length = $new_length;
        $this->width = $new_width;
        $this->fg_color = $newFgColor;
        $this->bg_color = $newBgColor;
        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * sets a new position.
     * @param int $new_x
     * @param int $new_y
     */
    public function setPos($new_x, $new_y) {
        $this->x_pos = $new_x;
        $this->y_pos = $new_y;
    }

    /**
     * returns an array of the current position.
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPos() {
        return array($this->x_pos, $this->y_pos);
    }

    /**
     * sets a new size.
     * @param double $new_length
     * @param double $new_width
     */
    public function setSize($new_length, $new_width) {
        $this->length = $new_length;
        $this->width = $new_width;
    }

    /**
     * returns an array of current size dimentions
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSize() {
        return array($this->length, $this->width);
    }

    /**
     * sets a new CSS hex color code for the foreground.
     * @param string $new_FgColor
     */
    public function setForeground($new_FgColor) {
        $this->fg_color = $new_FgColor;
    }

    /**
     * returns the current CSS hex color code for the foreground.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getForeground() {
        return $this->fg_color;
    }

    /**
     * sets a new CSS hex color code for the background.
     * @param string $new_BgColor
     */
    public function setBackground($new_BgColor) {
        $this->bg_color = $new_BgColor;
    }

    /**
     * returns the current CSS hex color code for the background.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBackground() {
        return $this->bg_color;
    }

    /**
     * returns a string describing current state of all attributes.
     * @return string
     */
    function _toString() {
        return "Position: (" . $this->x_pos . ", " . $this->y_pos . ")\n"
                . "Size: " . $this->length . " by " . $this->width . "\n"
                . "Color: Fore(" . $this->fg_color . ") Back(" . $this->bg_color . ")";
    }

}
```

Comment: it helps to post the actual errors you are getting rather than 'and i get errors'. but a) php doesn't support constructor overloading, and b) php constructors are named`__construct()` not `classname()`. [heres some reading](http://verraes.net/2014/06/named-constructors-in-php/)

Comment: you may want to mark the factory methods there as static, depending on how you intend to use the class

Comment: what do you mean by factory methods?

Comment: your `with/withoutPosition` methods that look like they are supposed to substitute for overloaded constructors

Comment: This should be moved to codereview stackexchange

Comment: will do and I will close this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access a class's properties within the class, you need to use `$this->x_position`  instead of just `$x_position`. Plus the constructor you are trying to define will go like this,

```
public function __construct($x = 0, $y = 0) {
  $this->x_position = $x;
  $this->y_position = $y;
}
```

now if you call the default constructor, without arguments, it will use the default values, and if you do provide arguments when calling it, it will use the values provided.